# Adding notes permissions in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online

We recently moved from Google to Sharepoint online and we are missing some features.

For example, we'd like to give users access to add note to a document without giving them edit permissions.

Is it doable?

Comment: You can add new role /_layouts/15/role.aspx Click add new /_layouts/15/addrole.aspx  Check only edit item.